# std vector readonly subview without an additional copy

Tags: c++, vector, c++17

In C++17, [string view](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string_view) is introduced to avoid unnecessary copies of a string when substrings are extracted. Is there anything similar for `std::vector`?

Something like this:

```
TreeType::TreeType(const std::vector<int> &list)
{
    if(list.size()>=2)
    {
        left=TreeType(list.sub_view(0,list.size()/2-1));
        right=TreeType(list.sub_view(list.size()/2,list.size()-1));
    }
    else
        ....
}
```

Comment: No there's nothing like that. But using [`std::basic_string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) as a blueprint it should not be to hard to create something like that for more generic contiguous containers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, should I [propose](https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal) it?

Comment: Have a look at [`gsl::span`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL).

Comment: just curiously, since many operator/operation valid on `string` can not be used on `vector`, is there any benefit from using a `vector view` instead of `begin-end iterator pair` or `begin-size`?

Comment: @appleapple, just preferred to avoid both pointers and `[begin,end)` convention complexities.

Comment: @O'Neil, thanks for your comment. Still doubt denigrating myself by using microsoft products.

Comment: the views in [ranges](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) might be worth looking at

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: And hopefully without all those unnecessary find operations that should be relegated to <algorithm>

Comment: @ar2015: The GSL is not a "Microsoft product". GSL is a library designed for the C++ core guidelines. That particular implementation is written by Microsoft, but there are other GSL implementations written by others.